# Does boost::variant work with std::string?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, variant, wstring

I've written a simple program in C++ with use of boost::variant. Program's code is presented below.

```
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <boost/variant.hpp>

    int main (int argc, char** argv)
    {
        boost::variant<int, std::wstring> v;
        v = 3;
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

But when I try to compile this with command

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -lboost_system
```

i get

```
/usr/include/boost/variant/detail/variant_io.hpp:64: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘((const boost::detail::variant::printer<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >*)this)->boost::detail::variant::printer<std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::out_ << operand’
```

followed by a bunch of candidate functions.

What I'm missing? The funny thing is When I use `std::string` instead of `std::wstring` everything works great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `wstring` cannot be `<<` in `cout`. Try using `wcout` instead. This is not a problem with the variant.

Comment: One more question: what should I do when I want to mix string and wstring in boost::variant? In that case wcout doesn't work.

Comment: Don't really now. It may not be possible. Maybe you could create a visitor to output to `cout` or `wcout` depending on the type contained in the variant, but that won't allow you the nice syntax `std::cout << v`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `wcout`, not `cout`. Because you're using `wstring`, not `string`.

```
std::wcout <<  v << std::endl;
   //^^^^ note
```

Demo : http://ideone.com/ynf15